# Problems with tracking clicks

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying a Slots Machine type program in Visual Basic, I have the basic slots mechanism all checked out and program with

```
Private Sub roll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles roll.Click
    a.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))
    b.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))
    c.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))

    If a.Text = 7 And b.Text = 7 And c.Text = 7 Then
        MessageBox.Show("WINNER!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you are not a winner.")
    End If
End Sub
```

But I want to refer to this clicked event in a secondary text label. Such as if the button was clicked it tracks how many times you clicked. Like I was thinking:

```
Private Sub amountlabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles amountlabel.Click
    for roll.Click do

        amount.Text = + 1
    End For
End Sub
```

Can anyone help thanks!

Comment: What has this to do with Lua? BTW it is Lua, not LUA. It is not an acronym, but the Portuguese word for "Moon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a counter variable (`Integer`) in your form class and every time the button is clicked just increment the counter and update the label's text, like this:

```
Public Class Form1 Inherits Form
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub roll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles roll.Click
        a.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))
        b.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))
        c.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))

       If a.Text = 7 And b.Text = 7 And c.Text = 7 Then
           MessageBox.Show("WINNER!")
       Else
           MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you are not a winner.")
       End If

       ' Increment counter
       counter = counter + 1

       ' Update display
       amount.Text = counter.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```